# When Flyway outOfOrder is enabled, what determines script execution order for multiple migrations?

Tags: flyway

If I enable the outOfOrder option in Flyway, what determines the execution order of migration scripts if Flyway discovers there are more than 1 migrations that have not yet been executed? Will it use version numbers if they exist on the new migrations' filenames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, version numbers as usual.

Comment: patience please... I just woke up and read Axel's response so now I'll mark it.